# Facebook Graph API Search Issue

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I created a search bar that uses the graph API and it worked fine until about a month ago. You could type something into the search bar, and get info back from Facebook related to your search parameter. It stopped working for some reason. So I went to my browsers search bar to type in a graph search manually like this-

http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=zombies

This doesn't work anymore either and I get an error message that says this-

{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}

Was there an update that made my search stop working? I've been reading Facebook's documentation and I can't find what I'm looking for. Can someone help me get this working again? My search is located at http://ericnaff.com/html5/p3. Here's my script that I am using-

function searchFB(userSearchparameter) {

```
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=' + userSearchparameter + '&type=post&callback=?', function(fbResults){
    $.each(fbResults.data, function() {
        // Data Templating
        $('<article class="fbResults"></article>').append ( 

            '<section class="resultsSource"><h6 class="shareHeader">' +
            '<img class="fromUser" src="https://graph.facebook.com/' + this.from.id + '/picture" height="50" width="50" alt="' + this.from.name + '">' +
            '<a href="http://www.facebook.com/' + this.from.id + '" class="fromName">' + this.from.name +'</a> shared a <a class="typeLink" href="' + this.link + '">' + this.  
            type + '</a> </h6>' +
            '<time class="createdTime" datetime="' + this.created_time + '">' + fuzzyFacebookTime(this.created_time.replace(/-/g,'/')) + ' &middot;</time>' +
            '<img class="typeLinkIcon" src="' + this.icon + '" alt="icon"></section>' +
            '<section class="resultsDescription"><h6><a class="shareLink" href="' + this.link + '">' +
            '<img class="sharePicture" src="' + this.picture + '" height="90" width="90" alt="' + this.from.id + '">' +
            '<span class="shareName">' + this.name + '</span>' +
            '<span class="shareCaption">' + this.caption + '</span>' +
            '<span class="shareDescription">' + this.message + '</span>' +
            '</a></h6></section>' +
            '<iframe class="linkShare" src="http://facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.link + '"></iframe>'
        ).appendTo('body');
```

I know it says I don't have the correct access token in my error, but it never used one in the first place and worked fine. If I need to add one, where would I want to include that? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need an access token; this means an [registered Facebook App][1]

[Facebook API changes Jul 10 '13:](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/03/platform-updates--operation-developer-love/)

> Graph API search changes
>
> App access tokens will be required for all search Graph API calls except Places and Pages.
> Search for application will no longer be supported.

1. Create an Facebook developer account
2. Create a new Facebook App
3. GET https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=APP_ID&client_secret=APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials
4. Append the returned access_token=... to your search requests

Comment: I just registered the app in the developers section. I got an app ID and secret. Do I put that information somewhere? If so, where would I want to put it? Do I need an actual access token, or is it auto generated?

Comment: updated the answer, you will need to get an url once to get the access_token

Comment: So I would put it here?- 'https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=' + userSearchparameter + '&type=post&callback=?' + 'access_token=?????

Comment: add a & before it; also you can omit the callback=?:
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=' + userSearchparameter + '&type=post&access_token=??????', function(fbResults){

Comment: The type=post is also not needed in your case:
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/search?q='+userSearchparameter+'&access_token=??',func..

Comment: I added the callback for IE. Is it not needed anymore? So should my string look like this?- https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=' + userSearchparameter + '&type=post&callback=?' + '&access_token=????'

Comment: yes.

but just try this:
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=zombies&access_token=562018750528704|2STCTSlGs8A1B3LOR5MvBLWNaPc

Comment: It worked! Thank you sooooo much. What a pain that was trying to figure out what and where the problem is. Now to try it in IE without the callback. Just tried, and I have to have the callback for IE. Didn't work at first, then added the callback. Worked!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34555/discussion-between-eric-naff-and-phiresky)

Answer (score 1):

Access tokens will also be required for Post searches too:

From [Facebook's Developer Roadmap of Completed Changes](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/completed-changes/):

> Graph API search changes
>
> User access tokens will be required for all search Graph API calls except **Posts**, Places
>   and Pages. App access tokens may also be used for **Post** search Graph API calls. Places and
>   Pages search Graph API calls will still require an App access token. Search for Applications
>   will no longer be supported.