# Facebook Search API with email address not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

Trying to do a search through the Facebook API using the search of graph. I know that when logged into my personal email, I can search people via email address rather than their name.

```
http:///www.graph.facebook.com/search?type=user&q=myemail@email.com
```

Returns this:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 200
  }
}`

Although I am using the API explorer which should work.

Any ideas? Is this not available anymore? I found other posts that had it working [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8595396/facebook-graph-api-search-by-email-suddenly-stopped-working)

Is there a way to do this via FQL?

Comment: No solution other than facebook has disabled it

Comment: Duplicate question (answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17977385/facebook-graph-api-search-issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook API does not allow search user by email.

Comment: doesn't it? by one can do that via facebook's web site in their account using the search box.

Comment: You can "do that via facebook's web site in their account using the search box" but not via API.