# Search for user by email address?

Tags: facebook

I've come across a few questions on here that have asked the same thing but they might be outdated now.

I'm just trying to query the Graph API to search for a user by an email address. I've been trying:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={EMAIL}&type=user&access_token=***
```

But that returns an error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "(#200) Must have a valid access_token to access this endpoint",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 200
   }
}
```

Is this not supported anymore? If I just search a name instead of an email it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like this behavior was removed from the Facebook API a couple of months ago. Here's a related question from early November:

[Facebook Search API with email address not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19746530/facebook-search-api-with-email-address-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a perfect solution by any means, but it's probably better than nothing.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.facebook.com/search.php?q=".rawurlencode($email));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.73.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.1 Safari/537.73.11');
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$response = html_entity_decode($response);
$response = explode(',"id":', $response);
$id = $response[1];
$id = substr($id, 0, strpos($id, ',')); //FB ID of the first person in the results.
```

It seems to return far fewer results than a graph search would, but it works for a lot of people, assuming their privacy settings aren't cranked all the way up.